# How to switch between screens?

Tags: android

I'm new in the android develop world. 
I created simple application and created a simple GUI with one button. 
If the user presses this button, I want to change the screen to show some other GUI.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this:

```
import android.view.View;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.your_button_id);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(your_present_activity.this, target_activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Mudassir I have edited the code.please check.Will you plz remove your DV.

Comment: Buddy, I didn't downvoted. And the second upvote is also mine.

Answer (score 3):

For moving from one [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) to another Activity, you need to use [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

For example, you are having one activity "A" contains button and second activity "B", and you want to move from "A" to "B" then write:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Practical and informative examples for the Intent are here: [Android Intents - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html)

Answer (score 2):

Set the button's onClick to a method that uses Intent.

XML:

```
<Button
    android:onClick="to_different_page"/>
</Button>
```

Java method:

```
public void to_different_page(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, browse_post_activity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way,Button in an XML graphical layout and implement a button click listener together with an `onclick` method. The `onclick` method will start a new activity using an intent.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonClick"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Now go to your Class

```
// Locate the button in activity_main.xml
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClick);

    // Capture button clicks
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            // Start NewActivity.class
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AddYourNewActivityName.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps .

For details http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidIntent/article.html

Answer (score 2):

A better word than "Screen" is "**Activity**", You switch between Activities in android.

A very simple way is to **create a button** on one activity (Lets call this First Activity) and assign it a method like `onClick = startSecondActivity` **in the .xml file**.

**Open FirstActivity.java,** **Add the method** startSecondActivity inside the main method as shown below. This will work!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set the content of the activity to use the activity_main.xml layout file
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void startSecondActivity(View view){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```